# Fail Jenkins pipeline stage if some file contains specific strings

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I need to fail one Jenkins pipeline stage when one file contains 'errors'
I do not know how to return an error from bash to Jenkins

```
   stage('check if file continas error and exit if true') {
        steps {
                sh "grep 'error' filetocheck.txt"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to capture the stdout from the sh DSL command in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507410/is-it-possible-to-capture-the-stdout-from-the-sh-dsl-command-in-the-pipeline)

Answer (score 4):

reference [Is it possible to capture the stdout from the sh DSL command in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507410/is-it-possible-to-capture-the-stdout-from-the-sh-dsl-command-in-the-pipeline)

This worked for me,

```
def runShell(String command){
    def responseCode = sh returnStatus: true, script: "${command} &> tmp.txt"
    def output =  readFile(file: "tmp.txt")
    return (output != "")
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('check shellcheck') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (runShell('grep \'error\' file_to_parse.txt')) {
                        sh "exit 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `String.count(charSequence)` where `String` could be a file or string.

```
def file = 'path/to/file.txt'
if ( file.count('error') > 0 )
    return stageResultMap.didB2Succeed = false
```